# Не правильно работает возврат к предыдущему фрагменту Navigation Component, при использовании TabLayout и ViewPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, navigation

Пишу небольшое приложение чтобы разобраться в основах **Navigation Component**, создал граф, создал пару фрагментов, сделал переход от одного к другому и передачу аргументов все работает.
Решил попробовать добавить на первый фрагмент **TabLayout** и **ViewPager** все работает, только вот теперь при возврате с второго фрагмента на первый, там пусто и не один из фрагментов в **ViewPager** не погружается а **TabLayout** подвисает. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело и как поправить? Может я вообще не так подхожу к этой задаче, не совсем понимаю как правильно реализовывать схему с **TabLayout** и **ViewPager** в **Navigation Component**, посоветуйте пожалуйста как правильно?!

**MainActivity**

```
var navController: NavController? = null

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainFragment**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        val tab_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout) as TabLayout
        val pager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager) as ViewPager

        initTab(tab_layout, pager)

        return view
    }

    private fun initTab(tab_layout: TabLayout, pager: ViewPager) {
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))

        tab_layout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL

        val adapter = MyPagerAdapter(activity!!.supportFragmentManager, tab_layout.tabCount)
        pager.adapter = adapter

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout))

        tab_layout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                pager.currentItem = tab.position

            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }
        })

    }

}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ForecastFragment**

```
class ForecastFragment() : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forecast, container, false)
        val btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn) as Button

        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putString("Hello", "Hello")
        }

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            navController?.navigate(R.id.detailForecastFragment, bundle)
        }

        return view
    }

}
```

**fragment_forecast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ForecastFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**DetailForecastFragment**

```
class DetailForecastFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_forecast, container, false)
        val detail_forecast = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_forecast) as TextView

        detail_forecast.text = arguments?.getString("Hello")

        return view
    }
}
```

**MyPagerAdapter**

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, internal var numOfTabs: Int) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                return ForecastFragment()
            }
            1 -> {
                return BlankFragment()
            }
            2 -> {
                return BlankFragment2()
            }
            else -> {
                return BlankFragment3()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return numOfTabs
    }
}
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/forecastFragment"
        android:name="com.example.weatherforecastapp.ForecastFragment"
        android:label="fragment_forecast"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_forecast">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment2_to_detailForecastFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailForecastFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/detailForecastFragment"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailForecastFragment"
        android:name="com.example.weatherforecastapp.DetailForecastFragment"
        android:label="fragment_detail_forecast"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail_forecast" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.weatherforecastapp.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Вы используете ViewPager2?

Comment: @Crush Нет первый

Comment: Попробуйте наследовать адаптер от FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: @Crush Увы, все так же

Comment: @Crush не совсем так же, начали появляться фрагменты после возврата, но не сразу и TabLayout все равно фризит

Comment: по фризам не подскажу, где-нибудь в Вашем коде есть сложные вычисления в UI-потоке или искусственные задержки?

Comment: @Crush нет все что есть описал, специально не добавлял пока не чего лишнего, чтобы разобраться